# How to get duplicate numbers inside a column and eliminate duplication but add the numbers opposite it and put it inside one of them

Tags: php, sql, select, operators, where-clause

[image of data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cHwd.png)

I want this data to be extracted , in which the iteration operation is eliminated and the value of duplicate numbers is added.

where the iteration operation in the left column (year) is omitted.
and the value of the numbers in the opposite column
which was duplicated in the first column, be summed up in one of them **by select in a php page**

like this: [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbPTq.png)

```
$test= $conn->prepare("SELECT *FROM years WHERE date BETWEEN 1990 AND 1993;");
$test->execute();
$test= $test->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

<?php foreach($test as $tes){
echo $tes['date'].$tes['numbers'];
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT is the attribute you are looking for which hides the duplicate data on your table.

```
$test= $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT columnName FROM years WHERE date BETWEEN 1990 AND 1993;");
$test->execute();
$test= $test->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```